# How can I extract the first node value from a XMLTYPE?

Tags: sql, oracle, extract, xmltype

I have a xml which is in a clob field of my table

This is the code I am currently using:

```
create table
   xml_key
(  
   mycol number,
   xml   clob
);


insert into xml_key
values(1653,
'<AppHdr>
    <Fr>
      <FIId>
        <FinInstnId>
          <BICFI>CRESUS33</BICFI>
        </FinInstnId>
      </FIId>
    </Fr>
    <To>
      <FIId>
        <FinInstnId>
          <BICFI>CAYTTRISXXX</BICFI>
        </FinInstnId>
      </FIId>
    </To>
    <BizMsgIdr>e9aab4a5-bc32-4548-93f6-aa47dd97d77</BizMsgIdr>
    <MsgDefIdr>pac.004.001.09</MsgDefIdr>
    <BizSvc>swift.cbprplus.02</BizSvc>
    <CreDt>2019-08-12T13:59:26+01:00</CreDt>
    <Rltd>
      <Fr>
        <FIId>
          <FinInstnId>
            <BICFI>LOYDGB21002</BICFI>
          </FinInstnId>
        </FIId>
      </Fr>
      <To>
        <FIId>
          <FinInstnId>
            <BICFI>CRESUS33</BICFI>
          </FinInstnId>
        </FIId>
      </To>
      <BizMsgIdr>1234567890</BizMsgIdr>
        <MsgDefIdr>pacs.008.001.08</MsgDefIdr>
            <CreDt>2019-08-12T12:59:26+01:00</CreDt>
        </Rltd>
    </AppHdr>');
```

when i extract BIC code from xml i have a problem.
I don't want double nodes like CRESUS33LOYDGB21002
How can I extract only CRESUS33 as FromBIC from xml?

```
 select XMLTYPE(t.xml).EXTRACT('//Fr/FIId/FinInstnId/BICFI/text()').getStringVal()  fromBIC,
     XMLTYPE(t.xml).EXTRACT('//Rltd/Fr/FIId/FinInstnId/BICFI/text()').getStringVal()  RltdFromBIC
          from xml_key t
         where mycol=1653 ;
    
    FROMBIC                           RLTDFROMBIC
    --------------------------------- --------------------------------------
    CRESUS33LOYDGB21002               LOYDGB21002
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using `//Fr` as a shortcut in both extract calls, and as `Fr` is a node both directly under `AppHdr` and under `AppHdr/Rltd` the first XPath matches both of those, and you end up with the values for both combined. The second Xpath is more selective so that only sees the second one.

If you give the full path for both then you won't have that issue:

```
 select XMLTYPE(t.xml).EXTRACT('/AppHdr/Fr/FIId/FinInstnId/BICFI/text()').getStringVal()  fromBIC,
     XMLTYPE(t.xml).EXTRACT('/AppHdr/Rltd/Fr/FIId/FinInstnId/BICFI/text()').getStringVal()  RltdFromBIC
          from xml_key t
         where mycol=1653 ;
```

You can also use XMLQuery:

```
select
  XMLQuery('/AppHdr/Fr/FIId/FinInstnId/BICFI/text()'
    passing XMLTYPE(t.xml)
    returning content).getStringVal() as fromBIC,
  XMLQuery('/AppHdr/Rltd/Fr/FIId/FinInstnId/BICFI/text()'
    passing XMLTYPE(t.xml)
    returning content).getStringVal() as RltdFromBIC
from xml_key t
where mycol=1653;
```

or XMLTable:

```
select x.fromBIC, x.RltdFromBIC
from xml_key t
cross apply XMLTable(
  '/AppHdr'
  passing XMLTYPE(t.xml)
  columns
    fromBIC path 'Fr/FIId/FinInstnId/BICFI',
    RltdFromBIC path 'Rltd/Fr/FIId/FinInstnId/BICFI'
) x
where mycol=1653;
```

| FROMBIC | RLTDFROMBIC |
| --- | --- |
| CRESUS33 | LOYDGB21002 |

All three return

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=2cab78e83cfde29f7d8605bc79f9ee4f)

---

If you're still on a version before 12c then you can use `cross join` instead of `cross apply`:

```
select x.fromBIC, x.RltdFromBIC
from xml_key t
cross join XMLTable(
  '/AppHdr'
  passing XMLTYPE(t.xml)
  columns
    fromBIC path 'Fr/FIId/FinInstnId/BICFI',
    RltdFromBIC path 'Rltd/Fr/FIId/FinInstnId/BICFI'
) x
where mycol=1653;
```

They [aren't exactly the same](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/lateral-inline-views-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-joins-12cr1#cross-apply-join) but shouldn't make a difference here.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=76ff74fac0ea4ab69ab6ed699036a2e1)

Comment: It is very good solution. I have voted it up but the third option is not working. SELECT query is having problem

Comment: @SachinPadha - you can see that it works in the db<>fiddle. But if you're on a version before 12.1 (I think) it won't understand 'apply' and will throw "ORA-00905: Missing keyword" - but you can change `cross apply` to `cross join`.

Comment: ohh yes. got it. "Cross join" is working